# C# make panel visible for specific time after mouse move over other panel

Tags: c#, mousehover

I need to make panel visible for specific time after mouse move over other panel
I have been solving this problem quite long. I tried to use Timer but I wasn't successful.

This is my code:

```
 this.MouseHover += new EventHandler(myMouseHover);

   [...]
   //event handler
   private void myMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                this.prevPanel.Visible = true;
                this.nextPanel.Visible = true;

                /* here I want put timer */

                this.prevPanel.Visible = false;
                this.nextPanel.Visible = false;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of timer you are using, you need to put the code that will hide your panel in response to the tick event.

For example, using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

// form constructor
public myForm() 
{
    myTimer.Interval = 1000;    // or whatever you need it to be
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);   
}

private void myMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     this.prevPanel.Visible = true;
     this.nextPanel.Visible = true;
     myTimer.Start();
 }

private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) {
     myTimer.Stop();
     this.prevPanel.Visible = false;
     this.nextPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

There are other timers you could use, but the WinForms timer has the advantage of firing in the UI thread so you don't need to worry about it.
One thing to note is that you need to think about what happens if the mouse hover event fires again before the timer expires.

Finally, if you are using WPF instead of WinForms, you could probably do the whole thing in XAML using animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Timer` and define `Interval` property

Property :

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer aTimer;
```

Init :

```
    aTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Tick += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Delegate :

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      this.prevPanel.Visible = false;
      this.nextPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that i need to make it inside mouseHover handler, so repeatedly after MouseHover action

Comment: I'am happy to help you, you can add Timer.Start method in your event in order to raise

Comment: This code generates an InvalidOperationException.  Don't use a System.Timers.Timer, its Elapsed event runs on a threadpool thread.  You cannot update UI from such a thread.

Comment: @AghilasYakoub: Timer.Tick not Timer.Ellapsed. Because consistent naming would be too easy!

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer ();

timer1.Interval  = periodAfterToStopInMiliseconds;

timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;

private void ActLikeIWant(double periodAfterToStopInMiliseconds)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     var timer = (System.Timers.Timer) sender;

     timer.Stop();

     this.prevPanel.Visible = false;
     this.nextPanel.Visible = false;
}

private void myMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.prevPanel.Visible = true;
    this.nextPanel.Visible = true;

    ActLikeIWant(periodAfterToStopInMiliseconds: 200);
}
```

Comment: If you move the mouse over the panel, then out, then back again, and so on, you'll be creating lots of timers.  That's probably undesirable.

Comment: Now you're attaching your method to the `Elapsed` handler on ever house over, so the code will be fired several times when the time runs out.  You should set the interval and attach the handler in the constructor.